# Create New Index While Merging Json Files

Tags: arrays, json, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have multiple Json files that have the exact same structure, except that they all have indexes ranging from 0 to x (e.g., 0 to 54; 0 to 60). I am seeking to merge them into a final Json file with a new index ranging from 0 to x.

**Overview of the Json files index:**

```
0:
 Title:
 Location:
 Price:
 Caracs:
    Terrace:
    AC:
    Lift:

1:
 ...
```

I've tried the concat method, but it just does not reorganize the data in a proper way. I sought documentation on multiple platforms, but none led me to make it work:

**Full code**

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('Belem_data_p1.json') as f1:
    data1=json.load(f1)
with open('Belem_data_p2.json') as f2:
    data2=json.load(f2)

df1=pd.DataFrame([data1])
df2=pd.DataFrame([data2])

MergeJson=pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
MergeJson.to_json('MergingMergersTrial.json')
print (MergeJson)
```

The data at best gets reorganized as such:

```
0:
   0:
     Title:
     Location:
     ...
   1:
     Title:
     Location:
     ...

 1:
   0:
     Title:
     Location:
     ...
   1:
     Title:
     Location:
     ...
```

The index of each file is just semi-ignored, and rows are grouped by 3 and placed in an index... I need for it to appear as such:

```
0:
  Title:
  ...
1:
  Title:
  ...
2:
  Title:
  ...
3:
  Title:
```

...

Here you can check Json file samples: [LINK](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f9416b5cdc78621320a1c109c01720ac20230101153732/740d41)

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you probably don't need pandas here, you can get away with a dict comprehension, something like: `json.dumps({idx: json.load(f"json_{idx}.json") for idx in [1, 2]})`, where [1, 2] is a list of numbers that represent the numbers in the filenames of your json files.

Comment: Hey there. Thank you for the input! I doubt this would work because I have many different files that will require to be combined between them as to form a final json file. So, I would have to manually update the index for each merging, which is not time effective :X

Answer (score 0):

Consider 3 json files:

```
a.json: 0-5
b.json: 0-3
c.json: 0-4
```

assuming that you want to get a single json like:

```
0:
   a: ...
   b: ...
   c: ...
...
3:
   a: ...
   b: ...
   c: ...
4:
   a: ...
   c: ...
5:
   a: ...
```

I think you can use:

```
import json

temp = {}
for name in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    with open(f"{name}.json") as fp:
         temp[name] = json.load(fp)

x = 5

out = {
    f"{i}": {
        name: temp[name][f"{i}"]
        for name in temp
        if f"{i}" in temp[name]
    }
    for i in range(x+1)
}

with open("out.json", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(out, fp)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you once again for your help. However, I am not familiar with the structure you are using to attempt fixing the index. I tried to apply it but the data returned did not have the expected format. I don't understand why it's so tricky to update the index when combining Jsons. The solution must be in a proper concat, merge, or join configuration. I'll upload how I fixed the issue once I do :)